# Trying to write the code to fill a field with smaller number

Tags: vb.net

Should be easier than I'm making, I'm sure.

`Field A` has a numeric value. I need to populate `field B`. `Field B` needs to be the smaller of the value in `Field A` or 620.

Tried:

```
[B] = Math.Min([A], 620)
```

Tried:

```
If [A] > 620 then  
    [B] = 620  
Else 
    [B] = [A]  
End If
```

When using either version, regardless of what value is input in field [A], field [B] is mirroring the value.  It never returns 620.
example: making [A] = 700, [B] should be 620 but it is returning 700

Comment: Please explain more in detail, it's hard to help with nothing to go on.

Comment: Come on, you can do this with a simple if statement...

Comment: The code you posted (both variants) should work correctly. What is the problem, what is the error? Oh, those brackets, they are wonderful

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a shortcut, that's what [`Math.Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. It returns the smaller of two numbers.